# If the professor says positive things about me, what are my chances of getting into the history graduate program?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, academic-history, history

I was just wondering from those who are knowledgeable about the history graduate school process — how much say do history professors have in accepting students to the program? I know they have some sort of say, but just how much generally?

I'm wondering because I'm applying to a really competitive school, and I recently met with the professor that I want to work under. The meeting went really well and he said that I was the first potential graduate student to ask intelligent questions about his writings and that he really enjoyed our talk. When I asked him what characteristics he'd want in a grad student he told me it was exactly what I had done with his work / how I analyzed his writing. He also sent me a list of his graduate students so I could talk with them and told me that he's looking forward to seeing my application.
Is this just jargon that history professors say, or does this actually give me some sort of shot of getting in? Should I feel confident about my application, or am I undermining the rest of the graduate process?

I should note that this is also a smaller PhD program, with about 3-8 students chosen a year (in Modern European studies, which is my concentration field). My GPA is kind of low because I was initially a business major (it is currently a 3.35 as of the end of my junior year) but my major GPAs for history and German are 3.75 and 4.0, respectively. On the application I've started, it also notes for you to list the specific faculty member you'd like to study under, so I would think he would read my application specifically. What influence does he have, and does it sound promising? Please let a stressed senior know. I don't want to get my hopes up either so please let me know if assuming too much.

Comment: We won't be able to put a probability on it, and it completely depends on the professor and program how much influence they have. Your chances if you apply are infinitely greater than if you don't. What does it mean to "undermine the graduate process"?

Comment: Completely uncertain, it’s tough to gauge your competition at this distance, but best of luck to you in your studies and subsequent career!

Comment: The influence of a professor during the student selection phase can vary considerably from institution to institution, so it's hard to tell. In any case, stay strong and don't give up easily, no matter what.